# Extract Data from ODT to PDF in Java

Tags: java, pdf, data-extraction, odt

I want to get the data of ODT file in java. I have two approach for that purpose.

1). I get the extract data from ODT file and create a new document

2). Get a print preview of odt document and add it to PDF document as a image like [this](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/hslf/examples/PPT2PNG.java)

Can you please suggest which approach is better and how should I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I used third approach. While searching for my answers I stumbled upon a JAVA library for my Purpose `XdocReport` . I used there ODT and DOCX converters to convert ODT/DOCX to PDF format.

Answer (score -1):

For the extraction:
 1) you can use pure Java, unzip the file and process the (mostly) content.xml file.
 2) you can use the the LibreOffice Java SDK to create a bridge to LibreOffice and programmatically extract the text.  There is sample code to do this in the SDK.

For the conversion:
 1) you can do it from the command line (again using Libre Office):
   soffice --convert-to pdf 
 2) you can drive it programmatically using the SDK as for #2 above.  There is a blog [Converting Documents to PDF](https://www.docmosis.com/company/blog/14-january-2016.html) I wrote a while back which shows an example of this with a focus on Doc input (but ODT is the same).

It depends on how often you want to do it, performance constraints etc.

Comment: hey @Paul Jowett, i build some code following your blog about converting doc to pdf ,  but i got a question, i was wondering if you can take a look to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55621825    , i will appreciate

Comment: @Paul Jowett , could you please update the link?

Comment: @Julios_Rodmax - I suggest avoiding parallel/concurrent use of an soffice instance.  Too many things go wrong.